# HorizontalScrollView inside ScrollView - disable vertical scroll when horizontal scroll is in progress

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a parent which is ScrollView, which holds a HorizontalScrollView as one of it's child views. All works perfectly, but when someone is triggering vertical scroll, the horizontal scroll stops, or is jittering. On top of it, there is some bug in Ice Cream Sandwich which does not handle vertical movement on HorizontalScrollView well, if it is inside a ScrollView, which content is smaller than the screen (in that situation, there is no vertical scrolling). Jelly Bean android handles it properly, but IceCreamSandwich for some reason detects the vertical movement, and stops the horizontal scrolling.

How would I go about making the parent scrollView disable it's vertical scroll, when a horizontal scroll is being triggered? So when someone is scrolling horizontally the HorizontalScrollView, and while doing it, the finger wonders a bit on a Y Axis, I do not want the parent ScrollView to capture that vertical motion.

Any help with that?

Comment: you can disable vertical scroll using below code

Comment: I do not want to disable vertical scroll completely.