# SwipeToRefresh does not respect requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent() in Android

Tags: android, reflection, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to implement horizontal scrolling inside `RecyclerView` item. Everything work well except one issue. When vertical `RecyclerView` s in the top most position (it is wrapped in `SwipeRefreshLayout`) and user start draggin horizontally but then move finger down it starts SwipeToRefresh gesture (little circle starts to appear). I've tried to use `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608596/horizontalscrollview-inside-scrollview-disable-vertical-scroll-when-horizontal/22609646#22609646) but it does not help. So what I figured out is `SwipeRefreshLayout` does not respect `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` method. As you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java#SwipeRefreshLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29) it blocks `ViewGroup`'s behavior:

```
@Override
public void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {
    // Nope.
}
```

Is it possible to change this to call `super.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(b)`? For example using reflection api ?

P.S. It is not that simple as extent SwipeRefreshLayout and override method because it is inside of third partly library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporary disable it.

```
mPullToRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot. It solved my issue.
Do you know why did they do it like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.2.0-alpha01 now respects requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()